# SQL Server 2005 : split string into array and get array(x)?

Tags: arrays, sql-server-2005, split

I have strings in a database table like this:

```
Peter/Parker/Spiderman/Marvel
Bruce/Wayne/Batman/DC
```

Is there a way in SQL to extract specific values from  a string e.g.

```
Name = MyColumn(0)
SurName = MyColumn(1)
Character = MyColumn(3)
Company = MyColumn(4)
```

Thanks

Comment: Will you have a unknown number of slashes `/` in your data? Or will it always have 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know you will have exactly 4 columns, then you can also use this nested CTE version:

```
;with s1 (name, extra) as
(
  select left(data, charindex('/', data)-1), 
    substring(data, charindex('/', data) +1, len(data))
  from yourtable
),
s2 (name, surname, extra) as
(
  select name, 
    left(extra, charindex('/', extra)-1), 
    substring(extra, charindex('/', extra)+1, len(extra))
  from s1
),
s3 (name, surname, [character], company) as
(
  select name, 
    surname, 
    left(extra, charindex('/', extra)-1), 
    substring(extra, charindex('/', extra)+1, len(extra))
  from s2
)
select *
from s3;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2305c/14)

The result is:

```
|  NAME | SURNAME | CHARACTER | COMPANY |
-----------------------------------------
| Peter |  Parker | Spiderman |  Marvel |
| Bruce |   Wayne |    Batman |      DC |
```

Or you can implement both a CTE that splits the data and then a `PIVOT`:

```
;with cte (item, data, colNum, rn) as
(
  select cast(left(data, charindex('/',data+'/')-1) as varchar(50)) item,
    stuff(data, 1, charindex('/',data+'/'), '') data,
    1 colNum,
    row_number() over(order by data) rn
  from yourtable
  union all
  select cast(left(data, charindex('/',data+'/')-1) as varchar(50)) ,
    stuff(data, 1, charindex('/',data+'/'), '') data,
    colNum+1, 
    rn
  from cte
  where data > ''
) 
select [1] as Name, 
  [2] as Surname, 
  [3] as [character], 
  [4] as company
from
(
  select item, colnum, rn
  from cte
) src
pivot
(
  max(item)
  for colnum in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9370f/13)

Answer (score 13):

I'm assuming here that there are always exactly 4 parts.

If so, you could replace `/` with `.` and use the nice built in [ParseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function. The only issue from your example is that it counts from the end, so you'd need to be careful about which part you want:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(max);
SET @test = 'Peter/Parker/Spiderman/Marvel';
SET @test = Replace(@test, '/', '.');

SELECT Parsename(@test, 4),--returns Peter
       Parsename(@test, 3),--returns Parker
       Parsename(@test, 2),--returns Spiderman
       Parsename(@test, 1) --returns Marvel
```

If there are a variable number of parts, you'll need to find a string splitting function to do this for you, there isn't a good one built in. Many options can be found searching SO: [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql+server]+string+split](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%20server%5D%20string%20split)

Word of warning - if you try to use a number with `PARSENAME` other than 1-4, the result will always be NULL.